# how to debug javascript using google Chrome Dev tool for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome-devtools

I have installed Google chrome dev tool plugin in eclipse.
when i select debug as through chromium javascript (new configuration) it ask me to select a tab in browser. and open java debug perspective. 
but nothing happen in browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

In "Project explorer" see new temporary project (with chrome logo on icon) that holds all scripts from the tab. You can set breakpoint there for a start.

You also can link debug session with real source files (it's a bit tricky now):
['Source Mapping' on wiki](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/EclipseDebuggerFeatures#Debugging_on_Files_That_You_Are_Developing/Source_Mapping)

Comment: hi...thanks for the link...but still its not perfectly configured..... instead of V8 debugging, when debug as Chromium javascript , manually i have to add one more tab in browser and enter url for my javascript project. after doing this i am able to debug in virtual project................Is there any way , by that it can directly open the tab with specific url...........???

Comment: Not for now. It would be a great feature, but it's still in "to be done" state.